# Creating an action based on a mocked controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following test method that is being used to test a controller.

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void ResetTest()
    {
        var target = new Mock<PROJECT.Reset.Controllers.ResetController>();
        //var target = new PROJECT.Reset.Controllers.ResetController();


        FormCollection form = new FormCollection();
        form.Set("username","domain\\username");
        form.Set("password","testpass123");
        form.Set("confirmpassword","testpass123");

        ViewResult expected = new ViewResult();
        expected.ViewName = "Reset";
        expected.ViewData.Model = rm;
        ActionResult action = target.Object.;

        action = target.Object.Reset(form);
        ViewResult actual = (ViewResult)action;            
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

If I use the:

```
var target = new Mock<PROJECT.Reset.Controllers.ResetController>();
```

Then the action is being evaluated as null. If I change this to the line of code below that which is uncommented then the action is being set. Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mocking this? It seems that this is your actual SUT (solution under test). So, you  should not mock it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding about Mocking framework is may be incorrect. You should not mock the object which is you are going to test (controller object in your case). You can/do mock only for dependency objects.

Ex : Repository objects and etc.